# How to create an equation from the result of a function with symbolic arguments

Tags: r, function, sympy

The result of calculation `PQ1(p=1,q,A)-PQ1(p=0,q,A)` is **"2 - 8*q"**
I need to transform the result into an equation **2 - 8*q = 0** to find **q**
But my code produces the error below
*Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input '0'", ('', 1, 168, '__Rsympy= Eq( ( ( ( ( ( 1 * q ) + ( 5 * ( 1 - q ) ) ) + ( 0 * q ) ) + ( 0 * ( 1 - q ) ) ) - ( ( ( ( 0 * q ) + ( 0 * ( 1 - q ) ) ) + ( 7 * q ) ) + ( 3 * ( 1 - q ) ) ) ) 0)\n'))*

```
    A=matrix(c(1,7,5,3), nrow=2)
    library(rSymPy) #symbolic calculations
    p<-Var('p')
    q<-Var('q')

    PQ1 <- function (p,q,matr){
      result<-(matr[1,1]*p*q+matr[1,2]*p*(1-q)+matr[2,1]*(1-p)*q+matr[2,2]*(1-p)*(1-q))
      return(result)
    }
    PQ1(p=1,q,A)-PQ1(p=0,q,A)
    str<-PQ1(p=1,q,A)-PQ1(p=0,q,A)
    print(str)
    sympy("Eq(",str,"0)") # create an equation
```

Comment: Should there be a comma like `", 0)"`?

Comment: Yes, there should be a comma like `sympy("Eq(",str,",0)") # create an equation`. Thanks, you have solved the problem&equation.